# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and $f(x)$ be a continuous function. Conditions for $P(f(X) = 0) = 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a continuous real-valued random variable (for simplicity, we can assume $X\sim N(0,1)$) so that $P(X=a) = 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $f(x)$ be a nonconstant continuous (analytic or Lipschitz if needed) function such that 
$\mu = \mathbb{E}[f(X)] > 0$ and $0 < \text{Var}[f(X)] < \infty$.

I would like to know the conditions under which $P(f(X) = 0) = 0$.
Or at least, would like to estimate how small it is, e.g. $P(f(X) \ne 0) > 1-\gamma$.

Obviously, if we already know $A=\{x | f(x) = 0\}$, $P(A)$ is the quantity of our interest.
My attempt is as follows:
Since $\mu > 0$, it follows from one of the concentration inequalities that 
$$
P(f(X) > 0) \ge 1 - \frac{\text{Var}[f(X)]}{\text{Var}[f(X)] + \mu^2} = \frac{(\mathbb{E}[f(X)])^2}{\mathbb{E}[f(X)^2]},
$$
which does not tell much...

I thought this would be easy to answer but it is not straightforward at all.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The inequality you have found is essentially a version of the one-sided Chebyshev inequality.  I suspect that with your continuity requirements the inequality is strict, but can be approached arbitrarily closely

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your comment. Yes, I used one-sided Chebyshev inequality. Sorry I don't follow "the inequality is strict". You mean $P(f(X)>0) > \frac{(E[f(X)])^2}{E[f(X)^2]}$?

Comment: Yes: $>$ rather than $\ge$ since equality requires $f(X)$ to take just two distinct values

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $g$ the density of $X$ and by $Z_f = \lbrace x\colon \, f(x)=0\rbrace$ the zero set of $f$. We have
$$P(f(X)=0) = P(X \in Z_f) = \int_{Z_f} g(x)\, \mathrm{d} x.$$
Therefore, $P(f(X) =0) = 0$ is equivalent to: 
$$\text{for a.e. } x \in Z_f, \ g(x) =0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your answer is helpful, however, can we say something about $P(f(X) \ne 0 )$? Since I was considering the case where $X\sim N(0,1)$, your answer becomes trivial in this case as $Z_g = \emptyset$.

Comment: @induction601 I removed the last sentence which was incorrect. If $X \sim N(0,1)$ then $P(f(X) =0) =0$ if and only if $\operatorname{Leb}(Z_f) = 0$.

Comment: In the case $X\sim N(0,1)$ we would have that $Z_f$ has Lebesgue measure zero. The complement of such a set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. $Z_f$ would thereby be the complement of a dense open set in $\mathbb{R}$. This actually implies that $Z_f$ can consist of atmost countably many isolated points.
Conclusion $P(f(X)=0)=0$ if and only if $f$ has countably many zeros.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I disagree with your conclusion that $Z_f$ has at most countably many isolated points. For example, the cantor set $C$ is closed and has Lebesgue measure zero but it is uncountable. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: You are right, i stand corrected.